# Am I subnetting correctly?

Tags: subnet

If I subnet the IP prefix `172.16. 64.0/18`, shouldn't I be able to get 4 subnets? I was only able to get the following subnets:

```
Network ID - Range - Broadcast ID:
172.16.64.0    -     172.16.127.255
172.16.128.0   -     172.16.191.255
172.16.192.0   -     172.16.255.255
```

Which subnet, if any, am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By splitting the 172.16.64.0/18 network in 4 subnets you obtain:

> 172.16.64.0/20
>
> 172.16.80.0/20
>
> 172.16.96.0/20
>
> 172.16.112.0/20

Comment: Could you explain? I thought the network IDs would increment by 64 in the third octet. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `172.16.64.0/18` is a network from 172.16.64.0 to 172.16.64.127.255. If you need to subnet it to get 4 networks you have to take 2 more bits (2^2=4). It means `/20`.

Answer (score 1):

You are subnneting in a wrong way. This one if what you should do.
Will take 172.16.64.0/18 into binary(.64.)
172.16.0100 0000.0

you need 4 subnets:

0100 0000 /base

0100 0000
0101 0000
0110 0000
0111 0000

All of this subnets are /20. We take 2 bits of host parts in 172.16.64.0/18, that has been used in network.

172.16.64.0/20, 172.16.80.0/20, 172.16.96.0/20, 172.16.112.0/20

Answer (score 1):

ip address X.X.X.X consisted of two main parts [Network part] , [host part]
Network part can be consisted of two parts , fixed part called [network summary address] and tunnable part called [Subnet ID] , will reserved by host IPs .
in your example you provide us with the network summary address **172.16. 64.0/18** and you want to subnet this address into 4 subnets (sub 0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ).
let us present your summary address in other way 
[image]

as you know in binary if you want to represent up to 3 things you need at lest 2 binary digits (00 ,01,10,11) , simply to represent those 4 subnets we will get the two binary digits we need from the host portion as next

[image]

so that the network portion of the IP became 20 digits instead of 18 
and the subnets will be as shown

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 available subnets here

Network ID - Range - Broadcast ID:

172.16.0.0     -     172.16.63.255

172.16.64.0    -     172.16.127.255

172.16.128.0   -     172.16.191.255

172.16.192.0   -     172.16.255.255

But your question states :: If I subnet the IP prefix 172.16.64.0/18

So we have to start @ 172.16.64.0